# how do you set custom dimensions for evil icons using CSS?

Tags: html, css, icons

So I am using the [Evil Icons](https://evil-icons.io/) in my Front End web development.

Although they have their preset size, I would want to use custom.

However, after reading the [site documentation](https://github.com/evil-icons/evil-icons#styling) on styling I still do not understand how to change it :(

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed their css for `m, l, s` classes. and this is what i found.

```
.icon--l {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

As per my understanding you can create your custom class and apply it to icon. see below code

```
.icon--custom-size {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }
```

Just change the height width and create new custom class.

Comment: yup it did. Thank you. Changing the width and height of the class changes the size of icons.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom size

```
.icon--sm {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

2. Use the custom size by setting the `data size` property in your custom size.

`<span class='c-social-nav__icon__content' data-icon='ei-sc-github' data-size='sm'></span>`